# Column Header to center but column body right align

Tags: javascript

How do I align column header to center but the contents of column must be right aligned. So, far I have done this which is not working.

```
{
    text: 'abc',
    dataIndex: 'abc',
    align: 'right',
    style: { text-align:'center'},
    minWidth: 150,
    renderer: Ext.util.Format.numberRenderer('0.00')
},
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We need more information to be able to help you. You only tagged your question with `javascript`, but it looks like you're using some library to build a data table. We need to know what you're working with in order to be able to help you solve your issue.

Comment: What I have found is that the column header is still in the center even if the contents are right align. I did check by aligning the column header to right, left and center through css. but for some reason even if it is centered while viewing it, it is slightly left align.and that is only for the columns whose contents are right align.

Comment: You still haven't told us what framework/library you are using. What you posted is merely some JSON, but you're talking about table columns. Based on that, there's no way anyone can help you.